# Conversion of SQL group by to Entity Framework Lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, lambda

I have 3 tables A which has an ID and other fields, B which has an ID, and C has a many to many relation for the ID's in A and B

I made a query that gets the results that I need

```
select result.*
from 
    (SELECT max(A.AID) as AID
    FROM A, C
    where A.AID = C.AID
    group by C.BID) as x, A as result
where result.AID = x.AID
```

and I want to convert it to a lambda expression in entity framework. But currently the query is not efficient enough. How would I make the lamda expression in EF and also make it more efficient?

Comment: i don't understand why you use MAX(A.AID) since always A.AID=C.AID in every record returned, moreover i would try to change cartesian product (A,C) with JOINS, that could be more efficient in some cases (for example in access, i don't know if also in EF). ALso join with result table.

Comment: I am using MAX(A.AID) because I need the largest AID for each group of BIDs.

Comment: yes, clear, didn't see it well, mistaked GROUP BY C.BID with GROUP BY C.AID ;)

Comment: I think you should optimize your sql code before you convert it to EF. EF's sql generated code is hardly optimal and always entails a bunch of nested subqueries. Also, if table C contains the many-to-many relationship, why do you need to inner join table A and table C? Why dont you use max(C.AID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first order your results descending by the ID you want the max of, and then GroupBy that ID in the related table, then Select the First from each grouping you should get the results you need.

```
var groupedResults = tempContext.A.OrderByDescending(a => a.AID
).GroupBy(group => group.C.AID).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
```

This should return you an IQueryable of the A entity that you can then continue to modify with additional clauses if needed.